# Uploading to Wordpress Database

Tags: database, mysql, wpdb

Hope everyone is doing great. I have a small issue with uploading information to the wordpress database. I created a new table without the prefix. I created code based on what I've learned in stackexchange to upload data entered into a form to the DB.

The form works and I am able to receive the email. However, just before the email is sent, I also have code that send the information to the DB. the data stored into the DB just fine the first time, but when I run the script again, it does not store the information to the DB. I still get the form but the information only gets stored the first time. What could be stopping the script from storing more data in the table each time it runs? Below is the DB columns.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    id int,
    column1 varchar (255),
    column2 varchar (255),
    column3 varchar (255),
    column4 varchar (255),
    column5 varchar (255),
    column6 varchar (255),
    column7 varchar (255),
    column8 varchar (255),
    column9 varchar (255)
    );
```

The variables used and the naming conventions are all good because it did upload the data correctly the first time. But it only does it once. The database id column is listed as "Primary" and "Unique" Below is the script.

```
require_once('./wp-config.php');

// WP database connection
global $wpdb;

// Check the Connection
if($wpdb->connect_error){
    die("Connection Failed: " 
        . $wpdb->connect_error);
}

$tbl_name = 'table name here';
$sqlQuery = $wpdb->insert($tbl_name, array('col1'=>$column1,'col2'=>$column2,'col3'=>$column3,'col4'=>$column4,'col5'=>$column5,'col6'=>$column6,'col7'=>$column7,'col8'=>$column8,'col9'=>$column9));

if($wpdb->query($sqlQuery) === true){
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
    $recUpdated = "Records-Updated";
} else {
    echo "Error" . $sqlQuery . "<br>" . $wpdb->error;
    $recUpdated = "Record-Update-Failed";
}
```

My problem seems to be just after the code above. After it uploads the data once, I continue to get "Record-Update-Failed" as a result in my url after the form processes and redirects me to the next page. When I go to the DB, it doesn't upload, so the result is seems to be true. Why is it not uploading after the first submission?

```
$SendMail = mail($to, $subject, $message);
    
if($SendMail === true){
    echo "Message sent successfully...";
    header("Location: https://domain.com/house-bill/?Success&".$recUpdated);
} else {
    echo "Message could not be sent...";
    header("Location: https://domain.com/house-bill/?Failed&".$recUpdated);
}
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: `$wpdb->insert` does not generate an insert SQL statement, it actually does the insert, so when you call `if ( $wpdb->query( $sqlQuery ) )` you're not passing it SQL, you're passing it either `true`, `false`, or an error object. Also, why are you including `wp-config.php`? Standalone PHP files are very dangerous, and completely unnecessary. What you want can be achieved via a REST API endpoint or a CLI command, this would allow WP to load normally with its API and provide proper authentication controls, as well as putting your code in a plugin

Comment: ok, that is good to know. I have been working off what I could find in stack exchange and stack overflow and this is where it led me. Would you recommend some changes that could improve this? 

Instead of making it a standalone file, what can I modify to remove the wp-config.php? Should I just replace it with the wp_header() and wp_footer() ?

Comment: look up REST API endpoints and custom CLI commands like I mentioned, as well as WP Cron. You're far better reading the official WP developer docs on the developer site for these functions, a quick read of https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/ would have revealed very quickly that it doesn't return an SQL string

Comment: OK, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.